# Outlook Redemption - using RedemptionLoader without regsvr32 the DLL

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, mapi, outlook-redemption

I want to use the mail functions without registering the COM dll (regsvr32).
I followed the informations from:

http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#redemptionloader

so i initialize the dll with

```
private Redemption.SafeMailItem safeMail = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_SafeMailItem();
```

which shows the Eval-Popup. All good.
But when i assign the outlook mail item to the object

```
 safeMail.Item = mail; // of type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem
```

then this exception appears:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Redemption.ISafeMailItem'. This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '{0A95BE2D-1543-46BE-AD6D-18653034BF87}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).

After registering the dll with regsvr32 it works? But i dont want that.

**What am i doing wrong?**

EDIT:

- i tried it with registering the COM on the dev machine
- removing the COM and use the **Interop.Redemption.dll**

What it the intended way of using the Loader without registering the COM?

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20827140/1498669

Comment: Are you using multiple threads? .Net run-time runs into marshalling problems if it cannot find type information in the registry.

Answer (score 2):

Stepped over the trap of initializing the loader in the main Thread and calling methods in another...

see [Redemption + Clickonce = :-(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158347/redemption-clickonce)